# How to Print only 4 decimal places in python?

Tags: python

I am writing a simple program to verify the formula of derivate and in output I am getting too many decimal places which look awful.

I am pretty new to python. I want to only show four decimal places.

here is my code,

```
from math import *

x = -pi
h = 0.001
while x <= pi:
    print("d/dx sin(x) =  sin(x+h) - sin(x) / h :", (sin(x + h) - sin(x)) / h)
    print("d/dx sin(x) = cos(x): ", cos(x))
    x += h
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use string formatting while printing like this

```
from math import *

x = -pi
h = 0.001
while x <= pi:
    print("d/dx sin(x) =  sin(x+h) - sin(x) / h :", "{:.4f}".format((sin(x + h) - sin(x)) / h))
    print("d/dx sin(x) = cos(x): ", "{:.4f}".format(cos(x)))
    x += h
```

Answer (score 2):

use f-string and .4f like this:

```
print(f"{0.123456789:.4f}")
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to accomplish the desired output. Note, the rounded value will be of type `str`:

```py
from math import *

x = -pi
h = 0.001
while x <= pi:
    print("d/dx sin(x) =  sin(x+h) - sin(x) / h :", "%.4f" % ((sin(x + h) - sin(x)) / h))
    print("d/dx sin(x) = cos(x): ", "%.4f" % cos(x))
    x += h
```